# C# equivalent of Form.Activate event?

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6

What is the C# WinForms equivalent of the VB6 Form.Activate event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a Form.Activated event that appears to have the same behavior:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx

Comment: It has almost exactly the same behaviour, but it is slightly different. "In Visual Basic 6.0, `Activate` is raised only when switching between forms in the application. In .NET, the equivalent `Activated` event is raised in these situations, but it is also raised when switching from other applications." If you are actually porting VB6 code, this could cause issues. Excerpt is from Microsoft's [free book](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa480541.aspx) "Upgrading Visual Basic 6.0 Applications to Visual Basic .NET and Visual Basic 2005"

Answer (score 2):

"Activated" is the event you are looking for.

Edit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated(v=VS.80).aspx